# How do you pass function output by value in PHP?

Tags: php, coding-style

So, I've been trying to google this and I feel like an idiot for not finding anything with the help of Google, by searching here on Stackoverflow or on php.net.

If I have a function call like:

```
myFunction($myDateTimeObj->format("Y-m-d H:i"));
```

I will get warnings in my log files about how I should only pass variables as references.

So, just how do I pass the output from one function to another without doing something silly like the following snipped?

```
$myDateTimeObjAsAString = $myDateTimeObj->format("Y-m-d H:i");
myFunction($myDateTimeObjAsAString);
```

After all, if `myFunction` takes say, four arguments I may suddenly find myself struggling to come up with variable names which in my opinion tends to hurt code readability a whole lot more than "cramming" `$objName->function()` into the argument list of the function I'm calling.

Comment: If your logs are saying only pass variables as references, then what you've done above is probably the only way to do it. It's not bad if you `unset` those variables afterwards, it will only increase the number of lines in your code, but it's also going to be a lot better for code readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you defined `myFunction()` by yourself, then I don't see a reason why you should pass by reference. I would refactor the function to pass by value if possible. Passing by reference in custom functions should by rarely used in PHP - only if it as a **real** logical meaning.

However, if the function expects the argument passed by reference, you can't pass a function return value, only variables are allowed. That's it.

---

Just for theory, a nicer syntax be like this:

```
function fun(&$a, &$b) {
   // do something
}

// define the vars "inline" ..
fun($arg1 = function1(), $arg2 = $obj->foo());
```

However, this might look a little bit better but `$arg1` and `$arg2` are still defined in the current context (also after the function call). Also I still say that passing by reference should be rarely used.

Comment: Also, I was mostly using ``myFunction``to avoid using a specific function that expects a reference because that would've invited "Oh you're doing it wrong, use **this** function instead"-style replies that wouldn't have answered my question. :)

Comment: If it is a built-in function like `preg_match()` you can't do much. But in custom functions I wouldn't use passing by ref - unless you might a encounter a real problem that you think you cannot solve without. (even then you might ask a question here ;)